# Why DJI Mobile SDK needs a physical Android device and does not work with an Android virtual machine?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, dji-sdk

I need to use `DJI Android Mobile SDK` but in the documentation we can see that a physical device is required. Why? What does a physical device that does not have an emulated one have?. 
Is there any unofficial approach to running `DJI Mobile SDK` in an `Android virtual machine`?

This is the requirements:

```
Android API Level 19 or higher
Android Studio 1.5 or higher
Device support: Samsung S7, Samsung S8, Samsung tabs 705c, Samsung S6, Samsung S5, Samsung NOTE4, Samsung NOTE3, Google Pixel, Google Nexus 9, Google Nexus 7 II, Ascend Mate7, Huawei Mate 8, Nubia Z7 mini, SONY Xperia Z3, MI 3, MI PAD
```

I tried with Anbox but sample code does not work, white screen appears.

Answer (score 2):

The [current documentation](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/application-development-workflow/workflow-integrate.html#android-studio-project-integration) actually refers to using an emulator (my emphasis):

> If the App Key was generated correctly and the **Android simulator** or mobile device has internet connectivity, then the following should be seen: [...]

so I'm not sure that the SDK does require a physical device.

If the docs are outdated and the SDK really does require a physical device, one feature that I could imagine being the cause is support for Bluetooth, which the emulator [does not offer](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36972875).